# Setting cookie in response

Tags: playframework, play-framework-2.7

```
return ok(auth.render()).as("text/html")
                .withCookies(Http.Cookie.builder("name", username).withMaxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(900)).build());
```

Why am I getting a 500 internal error on this line. How do we set the cookie in play framework 2.7.
I get below error-

```
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Internal server error, sending 500 response
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:504)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
```

Comment: This is not a cookie problem. Can you post your play framework version and akka version?